# How do I get Pillager Patrols to spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't find a Pillager Outpost anywhere near my house, and so I've been trying to AFK far away from my house (it has a village and patrols don't spawn near villages). But there seem to be none spawning. Anything I might be doing wrong?

I'm playing Minecraft Java Edition 1.18.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the actual answer to your question, but you can easily locate a Pillager Outpost using this [Pillager Outpost finder](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/pillager-outpost-finder) site. The only thing you need is your world seed.

As far as I know Pillager patrols are spawned randomly, there's no reliable way to get one outside of their outpost.

From [Minecraft wikia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Patrol):

> Patrols spawn naturally after the world age reaches 100 minutes (5 in-game days), then after a delay between 10–11 minutes an attempt is made to spawn a patrol with 20% chance of success. After an attempt is made, the delay is reset.

You also need to check that:

> In Java Edition, patrols never spawn if `/gamerule doPatrolSpawning` is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Patrol#Java_Edition),

> Patrols can spawn during the day on blocks with a block light level of 8 or lower. If a player is within 5 by 5 by 5 sub-chunk cube around a village, patrols do not spawn.

> The game picks a random location 24–48 blocks along each of the X and Z axis away from the player to try to spawn the patrol's captain. If a pillager cannot spawn at the chosen position, it gives up and does not spawn anything. If the captain can spawn, the game tries to spawn 1 + localDifficulty [verify](rounded up) more pillagers, with each pillager spawning within a 4-block radius square around the previous pillager.

So, if you find a large open area and wait for long enough, a pillager patrol will spawn.

Please note, that Pillager Patrols only spawn **when your world reaches 100 minutes** or 5 in-game days. The game will attempt to spawn a pillager patrol every 10 ish minutes with a success rate of 20%.

So in theory, if you find a large open area, you should be able to find a pillager patrol in 10 minutes if you're lucky, or up to 50 minutes if you aren't.

Comment: "up to 50 minutes if you aren't", if you mean that 5x 20% makes 100%, that's not how probability works

Answer (score 0):

The patrols are based on certain factors: time, amount of villagers outside of a village nearby(so like make your own village at your base) and a few other factors. Get at least 10 villagers in your fake village (doesn't have to look like a village).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure, off of odds, that around every 50 minutes you would have around a 67% chance to get one, then increasing from there. Not sure though, this was after a lot of searches and an at least once rule, so correct me if I’m wrong.
The amount of time it would take for pretty much perfect odds 1%>a is 3 and a half hours.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).